# Search through array API JSON Vue

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js

This is my first time using Vuejs. I am building a web app where I load images from flickr API that are stored in an array. I would like to do a basic search bar that will filter the images based on the word entered but I am not sure how to do that.

I have in my template

```
<input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="search for image" />
...
<li class="media" v-for="flickrImage in flickrImage">
```

The function I have for searching is:

```
export default {
name: 'Flickrlist',
data() {
  return {
    flickrImage: [],
    search: ''
  }
},

computed: {
  filteredImage: function () {
    return this.flickrImage.filter((flickrImage) => {
      return this.flickrImage.title.match(this.search)
    });
  }
}
```

How can I pass the `filteredImage`?

Comment: In the v-for use the computed property you created **filteredImage**. Also are you sure you want to use String.match() there, since it matches against a regular expression, not a string.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the v-for I display a list of images that I get back from flickr API so if I replace it with the filteredImage my images no longer show because I have another method in my code to display the images using the flickrImage array. This is why I am confused about where to call the filteredImage. Would it be better if I show all of my code?

Comment: Yeah sure, create a fiddle with most of the code.

Comment: Link to the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/qt8m2rwr/ Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**You are not referencing the right variable in your filter function.**

```
filteredImage: function () {
   return this.flickrImage.filter((flickrImage) => {
      return this.flickrImage.title.match(this.search)
   });
}
```

Should be

```
filteredImage: function () {
   return this.flickrImage.filter((x) => {
      return x.title.match(this.search)
   });
}
```

Then you just need to update your template to

```
<li class="media" v-for="flickrImage in filteredImage">
```

Here is a working JSFiddle based on yours: https://jsfiddle.net/qt8m2rwr/1/

Comment: Thank you for your reply however this did not fix the problem. I noticed that in your fiddle you use new Vue and I use export default. Could that be causing issues? If I try to replace it I get the following error:"export 'default' (imported as '__vue_script__') was not found in '!!babel-loader!

Also, how would it know that I am using the flickrImages.title attribute to search on? The 'x' just stays in grey and it is unused.

Comment: @user2897724 Hi, it might not be your only problem but the you still need to fix the problem I identified. Also, no, the different way we use Vue is not related to your issues. I just used the mode compatible with all browser instead of import/export syntax that require ES6 or compiling.

Comment: @user2897724 The 'x' is the parameter you pass to the filter function. The filter function is called for each image in flickrImage and x is just the variable I used to identified the current image. In your code, "this.flickrImage" inside the filter function still refer to the list so it's wrong. It needs to refer to the current element.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense but that parameter stays unused. Why would that be?

Comment: @user2897724 This parameter is used at the line "x.title.match(this.search)".

Comment: sorry, my editor was telling me that it wasn't being used. The following error occurs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. Is that because x is not being used?Filter is used only on arrays right?

Comment: @user2897724 You get that error because the list "this.flickrImage" is not defined. This might be a problem with how you get the list.

Comment: I am not sure what that means but I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: I fixed the issue and the search now works. Thank you for your help